# Even though the correct id is set in the href of the anchor tag, my controller takes an id one behind

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-controller, laravel-eloquent-resource

**What I have**

***blade.php file***

```
<form action="cars/{{ $car->id }}" method="POST" class="pt-3">
    @csrf
    @method('delete')
    <button 
        type="submit"
        class="border-b-2 pb-2 border-dotted italc text-red-500"
    >
        Delete &rarr;
    </button>
</form>
```

***Controller in Laravel***

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $car = Car::find($id)->first();

    $car->delete();

    return redirect('/cars');
}
```

**Problem**

The above controller, always deletes the record in the db that is one id behind.
***For example, if the id sent in the request is 14, the controller deletes the record with the id of 13.***

Two other important details that relates to this question that I want to mention is,

***-> I have double checked the url that the request is sent to and the url holds the correct id.
So it has to be the controller that fails. 

-> Even though the above code for the controller does not work, the following code works perfectly
fine.***

```
   public function destroy(Car $car)
{
    $car->delete();

    return redirect('/cars');
}
```

**I can not figure out why the code I have typed under "Controller in Laravel" does not work while the code I have typed directly above this works.**

Comment: `$car = Car::find($id)->first();` after that line check `dd($car)`

Comment: As suggested above, dd the $id first and if that's ok, the $car after you fetch it. Also, what's your route look like?

Comment: $car = Car::find($id); use it

Comment: I die and dumped the `$id` and `$car` as @A.ANoman and @Drewster suggested. `$id` shows the correct id. `$car` holds the record for the first car in the database which is not as same as the `$id` I got when I die and dumped the id. (In short `$id` holds the correct result but `$car` holds the wrong result.) Now what I can not understand is why does not the line `$car = Car::find($id)->first();` provide the correct record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### routes/web.php

```
Route::get('cars', [App\Http\Controllers\CarsController::class, 'index'])->name('cars');
Route::get('cars/{id}/delete', [App\Http\Controllers\CarsController::class, 'destroy'])->name('cars.destroy');
```

##### blade.php file

I did added form action in route.

```
<form action="{{route('cars.destroy', $car->id)}}" method="POST" class="pt-3">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <button type="submit" class="border-b-2 pb-2 border-dotted italc text-red-500"> Delete &rarr;</button>
</form>
```

##### Controller file

Replace **find** to **findOrFail** and remove `first()`. and last get id using `$request->id`.

```
public function destroy(Request $request) {
    $car = Car::findOrFail($request->id);
    $car->delete();
    return redirect()->route('cars');
}
```

Comment: As you suggested doing `$car = Car::findOrFail($request->id)` gave me the correct result. However, If I do `$car = Car::findOrFail($request->id)->first()` gives me the first record in the db. I can not figure out why this happens. What I have in mind is I think appending `first()`, to `findOrFail($id)` , should get the records with the id of `$id` and then give me the first one among them.

Comment: Ok, but you use <code>first()</code> method it will return first recode in database.
"The above controller, always deletes the record in the db that is one id behind. For example, if the id sent in the request is 14, the controller deletes the record with the id of 13." Your database in first column id is 13 and you use first() method with pass 14 number id, so it can return 13 number recode.